# Bootstrap Datepicker with Asp.Net Textbox

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Maybe it will be a silly question but I couldn't handle my problem.  I checked all the questions and answers on here but I didn't find any clue.  Anyway, I want to use the bootstrap datepicker with asp.net textbox.  When I use it with input without the runat="server" tag, I see that the datepicker shows up, but when I try to use it with textbox with the runat="server" tag, the datepicker is not showing. Any idea on how to solve this issue?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DateTextbox" runat="server" CssClass="m-wrap span12 date form_datetime"></asp:TextBox>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dp = $("#<%=DateTextbox.ClientID%>");
            dp.datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
            language: "tr"
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 6):

thanks for your answers. i did a lil change on my code its working now. i am posting for further use.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dp = $('#<%=DateTextbox.ClientID%>');
        dp.datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
            language: "tr"
        }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            $(this).blur();
            $(this).datepicker('hide');
        });
});
</script>
```

but i dont understand whats make the diffrence between (") and (') ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DateTextbox" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="m-wrap span12 date form_datetime"></asp:TextBox>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dp = $("#DateTextbox");
            dp.datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
            language: "tr"
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not against simply using a class, you can leverage the `date` class on your input, like so:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('input.date').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
            language: "tr"
        });
    });
</script>
```

The disadvantage is that you're targeting more elements (potentially), but unless you have a crazy number of inputs in your form, it shouldn't make a noticeable difference.