# Error: datepicker is not a function language "tr"

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I got the following error while using datepicker.js

> TypeError: dp.datepicker is not a function
>   language: "tr"

I take the reference of this following link
[Bootstrap Datepicker with Asp.Net Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284421/bootstrap-datepicker-with-asp-net-textbox)

but it still gives the error.

Comment: I Solve this problem by adding a jQuery 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.css" type="text/css" />


   <script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
```

do not load the same script twice